# Multiple actor systems for an application

Tags: scala, akka

[This](http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2016/08/23/akka-anti-patterns-too-many-actor-systems/) article talks about how we should not create 'too' many actor systems. But the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/general/actor-systems.html) say:

> An ActorSystem is a heavyweight structure that will allocate 1…N
>   Threads, so create one per logical application.

I am unable to understand what is the real issue here with using multiple actor systems in an application. Also, is it possible for actors from different actor system to message each other?

Comment: @downvoter, can you please explain why this question was downvoted? I feel the question is related to programming, it shows research effort ( I have linked two articles ). I am asking help on something I dont understand as there are conflicting opinions on the subject.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no issue with using multiple systems. There is a potential issue with creating *too many* of them. The reason is that with an `ActorSystem` comes some non-negligible overhead - mainly because each one would allocate its own fork-join pool.

I recommend you read [this blogpost](http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2016/08/23/akka-anti-patterns-too-many-actor-systems/) for more info.

Actors from different `ActorSystem`s *can* message each other, but AFAIK this needs to happen through [remoting](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html). This counts as yet another reason why system segregation doesn't really make sense as a local pattern.

Comment: Remoting is only needed to cross jvm boundaries.

Comment: how can we find the actor from another actor system? without explicitly providing the actorRef. I guess `context.actorSelection()` won't work since they are in different context right?

Comment: Please showcase how to use multiple actor systems within single akka application?