# flink increase parallelism of async operation

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, akka-http

We have AsyncFunction the async operation is done using [akka http client](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/index.html)

```
class Foo[A,B] extends AsyncFunction[A, B] with {
  val akkaConfig = ConfigFactory.load()
  implicit lazy val executor: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.directExecutor())
  implicit lazy val system = ActorSystem("MyActorSystem", akkaConfig)
  implicit lazy val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    def postReq(uriStr: String, str: String): Future[HttpResponse] = {
        Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(
          method = HttpMethods.POST,
          uri = uriStr,
          entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, str))
        )
      }

 override def asyncInvoke(input: A, resultFuture: ResultFuture[B]) : Unit  = {
    val resultFutureRequested: Future[HttpResponse] = postReq(...)
//the rest of the class ...
```

Questions :

1. If I want to increase the parallelism of the http requests - should I do it using the akka config or is there is a way to config it via flink.yamel
2. Since Flink is using akka as well is that the correct way to create the `ActorSystem` and the `ExecutionContext` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first question, You have three different settings that can affect the performance and the number of actual requests executed:

1. Parallelism, this will cause the Flink to create multiple instances of Your `AsyncFunction` including multiple instances of Your `HttpClient`.
2. Number of concurrent requests in the function itself. When you are calling `orderedWait` or `unorderedWait` You should provide the `capacity` in the function, which will limit the number of concurrent requests.
3. The actual settings of Your Http client.

As You can see, the points 2. and 3. are connected, since the Flink can limit the number of possible concurrent requests, so sometimes the changes in Your Http Client settings may not have an effect, since number of requests is bounded by Flink intself.

Increasing the throughput of Your `AsyncFunction` depends on the case. You need to remeber that `AsyncFunction` is callend IN SINGLE THREAD. This basically means that If the time to respond of the service You are calling is big, You will simply block the number of requests waiting for the response and thus the only way is to increase the `parallelism'`. Generally however, changing the settings of the `HttpClient` and the `capacity` of the function should allow You to obtain better throughput.

As for the second question, I don' t see an issue with creating the multiple `ActorSystems`. You can see the similar question answered [here].[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254821/multiple-actor-systems-for-an-application)

Comment: This is a good answer - I wanted to add one more note, where often you wind up needing to configure the connection pool (make it bigger) in order for that to not wind up limiting your max rate. See https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/host-level.html